# CSS Tips and Tricks for Streamlining CSS Styles - Particularly Font Styles

Tags: css

I’m working on cleaning up my CSS file and am looking for ways to make it more streamlined and efficient.

One question in particular, that I have, is regarding defining fonts. I’m using a custom font via `@font-face`. Do I have to specify the following for EACH style?

```
font-family:
font-weight:
font-size:
font-style:
font-stretch:
```

Or can I specify only the first three?

Any other tips/tricks anyone has for streamlining a CSS file, would be helpful as well. Except for combining styles, I only do that for a few elements, currently, but I'm not advanced enough to feel comfortable in doing that for everything in my CSS.

Comment: All properties you listed are automatically inherited ([\[1\]](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html), [\[2\]](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-stretch-prop)) by child elements from their parents.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Streamline and optimize css is a good thing to do. You don't need to specify `font-stretch` for you fonts and sometimes not even style, size or weight either. If you are doing a huge project, surely that will help, but most often you won't be loading up your page with tons of fonts. And even if you are loading a few, you should keep in mind using Google Fonts to help you with page size.

You might want to look this site for a few extra tips: http://www.apaddedcell.com/21-ways-streamline-your-css

Comment: Thank you so much! This is helpful and that link is awesome! :) I do a couple of those tips already, but it gave a bunch of other tips that I'm going to look into implementing and using for future files as well.